# how to Host ASP.NET Core on Windows with Apache

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, web-hosting

I need to host my .Net Core 6.0 application on Windows with Apache. Do you have any tutorials? I found many tutorials to host on Linux but none on Windows. I have come across a similar question but can't find a good answer. I am using the Kestrel web server in ASP.NET Core

Answer (score 1):

Apache cannot host asp.net core webapp. You have to host by kestrel then use apache as reverse proxy.You can reference this tutorials:
http: https://gist.github.com/erodewald/cfed87b4ec3f362006bb 
https: https://community.qlik.com/t5/Official-Support-Articles/Quick-guide-to-configure-Apache-as-a-Reverse-Proxy-with-HTTPS/ta-p/1713172 
By the way, IIS is more convinient to host asp.net core webapp in windows.

Answer (score 0):

Apache Hosting for ASP.NET Core on Windows can be done with Xampp. See this [article](https://www.yogihosting.com/aspnet-core-host-apache-windows/) where hosting steps are given.